# how the Main method is used and what it's purpose is?

Tags: java

When using inheritance structure in java is the main method always in the last child(extended) class or should it be in the first parent class? And what is the main purpose of this method?

Comment: Having a main method inside a class that's part of an inheritance tree is a code smell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main method is static, and thus can't be inherited, and so your title is wrong; you can't "extend" the main method.

For many large projects that I've seen, it goes in its own class expressly built for the purpose, a class that is neither a "child" nor a "parent" class, other than being a child of the Object class.

Also understand that ***any*** class (or interface, enum,...), and multiple classes within a project, can have a main method, and sometimes this is used for testing purposes.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis: I simply decided to make this a community wiki answer so that anyone can edit it and contribute to it, and so that I get no reputation points for it.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis It's an easy answer and doesn't want freebee rep.

Comment: but the class can be extended (that's what I'm referring to).

Comment: @shaam: that has nothing to do with anything. The main method is a completely separate orthogonal concept. Where it lies is not as important as you appear to think it is.

Comment: @shaam static methods are no inherited, think of static methods as methods without class at all, class for them is namespace basically